# Login wih API. Session doesn't save

Tags: php, api, session, yii2

I send post request to the site, where the registration form is. With  identification process there is no problem, it creates session. But when I log in in the second site there is no session and I should authorize again to be logged in in my account.

Why the session is deleted after API request?

Comment: Because API request and next request you do after that are done without persisting session cookie I think. Provide some code for more details.

Comment: What do you mean by saying persisting? What part of the code do you need?

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure your application in config/web.php?
Be sure having "user" => "enableSession" set to `TRUE`.

If you're using yii for RESTful requests, use [BearerAuth](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-auth-httpbearerauth.html). You can find some guide [here](http://blog.neattutorials.com/angularjs-and-yii2-part-2-authentication/). It's a tutorial with angular, but you'll see how it works.